# How to build an hadoop2.2.0 eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, ant, ivy

I have been working on hadoop2.2.0 for a while, and now I want to develop and debug in eclipse, but the hadoop2.2.0 does not provide a plugin for eclipse. Can anyone tell me how to develop a hadoop plugin for eclipse. I have found a plugin in https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin, but encountered this error:

**java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file**

The ivy in this github project is ivy-2.1.0, but it still report this error, can anyone help me correct the build-contribute.xml in /hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin/src/contrib/. Any help will be greatful.

Comment: The link you provided was broken and the project has no build.xml file. Looks like a broken project to me

Comment: I have fixed the link.

Comment: I have foudn the plugin that works, and upload it to my cloud, here is the download link, hope will help those who need it.[hadoop2.2.0-eclipse-plugin](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1xjulK)